# regex to extract json string from text

Tags: php, json, regex

I'm looking for regex to extract json string from text. I have the text below, which contains.
My json:

```
[
  {
    "message": "(.*)",
    "answer": " :с"
  },
  {
    "message": "http:\/\/(.*)\.(.*)\/[\S\s]+\ ?",
    "answer": "No!"
  }
]
```

And php parse:

```
json_decode($json); //null
var_dump(json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX); //true
```

Comment: Where are you stuck in specific?

Comment: Just to make sure: `PHP` has some beautifully crafted [JSON functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) build in already - trying to do everything with regular expressions shows a lack of phantasy :-)

Comment: @Jan his issue is an invalid JSON input actually ;-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: ...ouch... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you call `json_last_error_msg()` you'll get the following:

> invalid string sequence

Indeed, the string `"http:\/\/(.*)\.(.*)\/[\S\s]+\ ?"` is **not** a valid JSON string per [the spec](https://json.org/):

[image: JSON string spec]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://json.org/string.gif))</sub>

Your string contains invalid escapes, such as `\S`, `\.`, `\s` and `\`  (space).

Instead, try to escape each backslash:

```
$str = <<<'END'
[
  {
    "message": "(.*)",
    "answer": " :с"
  },
  {
    "message": "http:\\/\\/(.*)\\.(.*)\\/[\\S\\s]+\\ ?",
    "answer": "No!"
  }
]
END;

$json = json_decode($str);
var_dump($json);
```

This works.